# how to click on different links of directory listing in a web page using selenium web-driver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website justdial where I need to click on every button (**Enquire Now**) of each profile. I tried below code also but it shows ElementClickInterceptedException.

```
browser.driver.find_element_by_class_name("green-btn").first.click()
```

I attached the image for a reference and the source code also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAsx4.png)

below is the inspect element code-

```
<li class="book-btn">
<!-- <span class="dtsbtntxt">Book a Table</span> -->
<!--  <span class="inner_spr in_po"></span> -->
                       <!-- <a title="Book Doctor Appointment" class="bookap green-btn result_loader_3 big_dn" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showloader('result', 'result_loader_3', this); _ct('DBookAppointment', 'lspg', '2'); openDiv('best_deal_div', 'bestdeal', '', '9999PX744.X744.130617175155.L7U9', 5);"><i id="result_loader_3"></i>Enquire Now</a> -->
                                                                                                                                                            <a class="green-btn result_loader_3  wdb" onclick="_ct('gtlp', 'lspg'); showloader('result', 'result_loader_3', this); trackEvent('Get The Lowest Price', 'onclicklowestprice', 'Get The Lowest Price');  return openDiv('best_deal_div', 'bestdeal', '', '9999PX744.X744.130617175155.L7U9', 5);" href="javascript:void(0);"><i id="result_loader_3"></i>Enquire Now</a>
                                                                            <span flg="2" docid="9999PX744_X744_130617175155_L7U9" countvalue="0">
```

Please help, how to click on each of this button using selenium web driver, I am using chrome web driver.

Comment: don't post images as they are generally of no use. Can you share the actual url? You will get more responses/help if you do. Secondly, what are you wanting exactly? It's possible you don't need to click the button to get what you are after, but by not providing a sample output, it doesn't give us an idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I want to click on each button with text "enquiry now". Below os the URL -https://www.justdial.com/Kota-Rajasthan/Doctors/nct-10892680

Answer (score 1):

To click on `Enquire Now` button induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and the using following locator.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class,'green-btn')][contains(.,'Enquire Now')]"))).click()
```

You need to import followings to exeute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there are n numbers of button, class- green-btn and       Text - Enquire Now, and I think this code will click on all Enquire button at the same time, but our requirements are to perform the click one by one, as per the listing.